# Cryptographic Strength of MDS Matrix

Tags: diffusion, mds

Maximum Distance Separable (MDS) Matrices are used for providing diffusion in a cipher. How to test the strength (with respect to cryptographic properties) of an MDS matrix used in a cipher?

Comment: What properties does the cipher need to assume from the MDS matrix?  If it's just whether it is, in fact, MDS, well, that's straight-forward to test...

Comment: The *only* strength any matrix can contribute to a cipher is diffusion. Since matrix multiplication is linear.

Comment: @kodlu: however, one could design a cipher which is weak with one specific MDS matrix, and strong with another.  Hence, it *can* be more than just the MDS properties; it can also be how well it plays with the rest of the cipher...

Comment: @poncho, could you clarify with an example? I can ask a separate question if you like. I havent seen MDS used differently than in AES, and I thought ( beyond efficiency) any MDS matrix would have the same diffusion/security properties since all MDS codes with the same parameters have the same weight distribution.

Comment: @poncho any update on this?